# Invoking method on java payload using MEL

Tags: java, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to invoke a method (getSubject()) on java payload using MEL. However I am getting exception ***unable to resolve method: java.lang.String.getSubject() [arglength=0]]***. Apparently it is assuming the payload is of type String where as it is  of type NotifyVO as shown in the log statement below.

INFO  2013-10-31 15:15:11,382 [[test].sendEmail.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: **payload : class com.test.NotifyVO**

The flow is --

```
    <flow name="sendEmail" doc:name="sendEmail">
    <vm:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way"
        path="send-email-vm" doc:name="VM" />
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="payload : #[payload.getClass()]"/>
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="smtpGmailConnector"
        host="${email.host}" port="${email.port}" user="${email.user}"
        subject="#[payload.getSubject()]" password="${email.password}"
        doc:name="SMTP" />
</flow>
```

Exception is --

```
Root Exception stack trace:
[Error: unable to resolve method: java.lang.String.getSubject() [arglength=0]]
[Near : {... payload.getSubject() ....}]
         ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SMTP transport is transforming your payload to a String in order to make it the body of the e-mail.

The solution for this is to store the subject in a variable prior to the SMTP outbound endpoint and use that variable:

```
    <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="payload : #[payload.getClass()]"/>
    <set-variable variableName="subject" value="#[payload.getSubject()]" />
    <smtp:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="smtpGmailConnector"
        host="${email.host}" port="${email.port}" user="${email.user}"
        subject="#[flowVars['subject']]" password="${email.password}"
        doc:name="SMTP" />
```

Comment: If you know that the `subject` flow variable will always be present, you can even use a shorter form: `subject="#[subject]"`